# Slash command not responding and error when I use defer() while coding a discord bot using python and nextcord

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

Im working on a discord bot using python. Everything is working perfectly fine, one small issue is sometimes when I use a slash_command it's returns : 'The application didn't respond'. Even if in the background the slash_command did the job.

I tried deferring using ctx.defer() but I get the following error message:

> 'Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has
> no attribute 'defer'

Im using nextcord and this is a sample of the code:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands, tasks, application_checks
import boto3
import traceback
import sys

client = boto3.client(
    'dynamodb',
    aws_access_key_id= '',
    aws_secret_access_key='',
    region_name='us-east-1'
    )
dynamodb = boto3.resource(
    'dynamodb',
    aws_access_key_id= '',
    aws_secret_access_key='',
    region_name='us-east-1'
    )
ddb_exceptions = client.exceptions

table = dynamodb.Table('')
table_edit_messages = dynamodb.Table('')

token=''

intents = nextcord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)

messages = {}
owners = [8350.., 4594.., 9094..]

@bot.slash_command()
async def start(ctx, guild_id):
    global owners
    if ctx.user.id in owners:
        await ctx.defer()
        client.put_item(TableName='XXXXX', Item={'guild_id':{'N':str(guild_id)}, 'guild_name':{"S":str(bot.get_guild(int(guild_id)))}})
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title= '✅ Bot started !', description='''The bot is started successfully for server: ` {} ` !'''.format(str(bot.get_guild(int(guild_id)))) + '\n' + '\n'
                                                                               + '''*Please check that the name of the server is correctly displayed. If not, it's likely that the bot is not in the specified server!*''', color=0xC86C90)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

I believe that reading/writing to dynamodb is the reason why the command takes more than 3 seconds to respond. By the way, this is not the command that returns the 'The application didn't respond'. It's another command that reads/writes from dynamodb and has multiple if/else statements.

**I have two questions: Why defer is not working and second question is there any other solution other than defer to make the command wait for more than 3 seconds.**

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] and the documentation that states that an `Interaction` object should have said attribute. For more information, please see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Question 1

Looking at [nextcord's documentation](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#context) - `Context` doesn't seem to have any function called `defer`

#### Question 2

One way you can make defer the command is by using a non-blocking sleep.

```py
import asyncio

asyncio.sleep(5)
```

That being said, the slash command expects a response back in 3 seconds.
[nextcord.Interaction.response.defer()](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/interactions.html?highlight=defer#deferred-response)

```py
@bot.slash_command()
async def start(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    global owners
    if interaction.user.id in owners:
        await interaction.response.defer()
        # Additionally sleep for more time if needed
        # await asyncio.sleep(5)
        client.put_item(TableName='XXXXX', Item={'guild_id':{'N':str(guild_id)}, 'guild_name':{"S":str(bot.get_guild(int(guild_id)))}})
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title= '✅ Bot started !', description='''The bot is started successfully for server: ` {} ` !'''.format(str(bot.get_guild(int(guild_id)))) + '\n' + '\n'
                                                                               + '''*Please check that the name of the server is correctly displayed. If not, it's likely that the bot is not in the specified server!*''', color=0xC86C90)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about if I do a ctx.send() at the start of the command and then another ctx.send() when the command finishes the task? Would it work in your opinion?

Comment: I haven't tried it - but maybe worth giving it a shot. I would still suggest you to follow the docs to avoid any undefined behavior in the workflow

Comment: That's not a `Context` object, that's an `Interaction` object.